# Proving that algebraic multiplicity and the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, isometry

I'm having some trouble proving the following:

> Let $f:V \to V$ be a linear isometry and $V$ a finite-dimensional euclidian vector space. Then, if $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue of $f$, the algebraic multiplicity and the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ are equal.

I know that, because $f$ is an endomorphism:$$\text{geomtric multiplicity of } \lambda \leq \text{algebraic multiplicity of } \lambda$$

But I have no clue how to even approach this problem. How can I prove this?

Comment: The concept of isometry isn't defined on a general finite-dimensional real vector space.

Comment: V is an euclidian vector space@JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is an isometry, $\lambda=\pm1$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$. In fact, if $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$,$$|\lambda|\|v\|=\|\lambda v\|=\|f(v)\|=\|v\|.$$

Suppose that the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is smaller than the algebraic multiplicity. Then there is an eigenvector $v$ of $f$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ (and we may assume without loss of generality that $\|v\|=1$) and there is a vector $w$ such that $f(w)=\lambda v+w$ (think about the Jordan normal form). Now, let $w'=w-\langle w,v\rangle v$. Then\begin{align}f\left(w'\right)&=f\bigl(w-\langle w,v\rangle v\bigr)\\&=f(w)-\langle w,v\rangle f(v)\\&=\lambda w+v-\lambda\langle w,v\rangle v\\&=\lambda w'+v.\end{align}But $\left\langle v,w'\right\rangle=0$. Now, note that\begin{align}\left\|f\left(w'\right)\right\|&=\left\|\lambda w'+v\right\|\\&=\sqrt{\lambda^2\|w'\|^2+\|v\|^2}\\&=\sqrt{\|w'\|^2+1}\text{ (since $|\lambda|=\|v\|=1$)}\\&>\|w'\|,\end{align}which is impossible, since $f$ is an isometry.

Comment: How can we conclude that $\exists w: f(w) = \lambda v + w$ from the Jordan Normal Form?

Comment: Form those blocks of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&1&0&\ldots&0\\0&\lambda&1&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&\lambda\end{bmatrix}.$$